# Constantly running a function in class in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm using `python-can` to poll a CAN bus for messages. I've created a class for this as follows.

```
class VS():
    def __init__(self):
        #code to initialise bus
        self.message = bus.recv() #to receive 1 message

    def speed(self):
        return self.message[1], self.message.timestamp
```

Now the bus outputs speed every 100ms so when I run the following

```
v = VS()
while(1):
    print(v.speed())
    time.sleep(1)
```

I get a timestamp separated by 100ms, instead of timestamp updated every 1s. This lags real time though as the messages seemed to be stored in a buffer or something. I want to rewrite the class/function such that I can get speed values at my desired interval (all greater than 100ms of course). I tried to run this via threading and redefined the speed function.

```
def speed(self):
    threading.Timer(0.01,self.speed).start() 
    return self.message[1], self.message.timestamp
```

Now this works but only for a while on my Raspberry Pi. I even check threads via `threading.active_count()` and it starts off with with 70, then throws an exception in thread 252 (`RuntimeError: can't start new thread`). The thread count then counts down from 252 to 0 in intervals of 10 then just returns constant values.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this myself. I created a thread in the constructor of the class. Also, it seems important to initialize the `self` variables used in the functions like `speed`. The rewritten code is

```
class VS():
def __init__(self):
    #code to initialise bus
    self.message = bus.recv() #to receive 1 message
    self.t = Thread(target = self.speed, args = ())
    self.t.start()

def speed(self):
    while True:
        self.message = bus.recv()
        return self.message[1], self.message.timestamp
```